# Textbox get focus when it is disabled

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I don't know how to let `TextBox` got focus when it is disabled. i try to let my textbox got focus from another element. 
Even when I write this code:

```
txtDateBourse.Enabled = true;
txtDateBourse.Focus();
txtDateBourse.SelectAll();
```

It is possible to do that ?

Comment: Probably you need to make it `ReadOnly` instead of disabling it.

Comment: even when i try it, it doesn't work

Comment: It doesn't work is not a suitable problem description. What happens when you set `txtDateBourse.ReadOnly = true;` and then click on control?

Comment: i didn't try to click on it, instead i try to make my textbox got focus from another  textbox

Comment: *Got focus from another textbox*? So you need to post a more complete code to show where/when you execute the code.

Comment: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.focus.aspx): _"Focus is a low-level method intended primarily for custom control authors. Instead, application programmers should use the Select method or the ActiveControl property for child controls, or the Activate method for forms."_

Comment: The question is not at all clear. Are you saying that you want to set focus to a text box that has been disabled? No, that is impossible. Disabled controls cannot have the focus. That's a hard rule. If it's disabled, the user cannot interact with it. Or are you saying that your disabled text box is getting the focus? Again, that's impossible, but you may be getting into some kind of focus limbo by manually trying to set the focus (something that you should not do, as Tim points out, by calling the Focus() property).

Comment: you may try to use setfocus() method

Comment: @Cody, i made the textbox enabled and then set the focus on it

Answer (score 0):

You cannot focus a disabled element.

If you want to focus this textbox, make it `ReadOnly` instead.

```
txtDateBourse.ReadOnly = true;
txtDateBourse.Focus();
txtDateBourse.SelectAll();
```

Comment: even with ReadOnly i can't make textBox get focus